# Scanning Strings then printing them along with integers

Tags: java

If the input would be 
Mandy 99 99 97 95 92 90 98
And the output needs to be
Mandy A 
the code i have so far is:

```
package utility;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LetterGrader {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String Name = new String();
            int quiz1;
            int quiz2;
            int quiz3;
            int quiz4;
            int mid1;
            int mid2;
            int Final;
            double grade;
            Scanner getScores = new Scanner (System.in);
            Scanner getName = new Scanner(System.
            System.out.println("Please enter name with test scores with a space in between each, in the order of "
                    + "Quiz 1 Quiz 2 Quiz 3 Quiz 4\n Midterm 1 Midterm 2 and Final\n");//Shows the format needed
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           Name = getName.next();
           quiz1 = getScores.nextInt();
           quiz2 = getScores.nextInt();
           quiz3 = getScores.nextInt();
           quiz4 = getScores.nextInt();
           mid1 = getScores.nextInt();
           mid2 = getScores.nextInt();
           Final = getScores.nextInt();

            grade =( quiz1  *   .10 +   quiz2   *   .10 +   quiz3   *   .10 +   quiz4   *   .10 
                   +    mid1    *   .20 +   mid2    *   .15 +   Final * .25);
            System.out.print(Name);
            if  (grade >= 90)
                System.out.println("A");
            if (grade >= 80 && grade< 90)
                System.out.println("B");
            if (grade >= 70 && grade< 80)
                System.out.println("C");
            if (grade >= 60 && grade< 70)
                System.out.println("D");
            if  (grade <= 59)
                System.out.println("F");

        }}
```

How would i scan what name the user inputs and then print it with the numbers?
Any help is great.

Comment: Not sure if `Scanner getName = new Scanner(System.` is a copy and paste mistake

Comment: i just had the line unfinished because i dont know what to put there

Comment: If that is always the pattern, use split function and get the first element as name and others as marks, and then evaluate it to get grade

Comment: Just a tip. for simple scripts like this, there's no need for more than one scanner. I would also use `else if` instead of a bunch of `if` statements to speed up the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the whole line and split it into pieces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         String Name = new String();
         int quiz1;
         int quiz2;
         int quiz3;
         int quiz4;
         int mid1;
         int mid2;
         int Final;
         double grade;

         Scanner getScores = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter name with test scores with a space in between each, in the order of "
                 + "Quiz 1 Quiz 2 Quiz 3 Quiz 4\n Midterm 1 Midterm 2 and Final\n");//Shows the format needed
        String[] inputs = getScores.readLine ().Split (" ");
        Name = inputs[0]
        quiz1 = inputs[1]
        quiz2 = inputs[2]
        quiz3 = inputs[3]
        quiz4 = inputs[4]
        mid1 = inputs[5]
        mid2 = inputs[6]
        Final = inputs[7]

         grade =( quiz1  *   .10 +   quiz2   *   .10 +   quiz3   *   .10 +   quiz4   *   .10 
                +    mid1    *   .20 +   mid2    *   .15 +   Final * .25);
         System.out.print(Name);
         if  (grade >= 90)
             System.out.println("A");
         if (grade >= 80 && grade< 90)
             System.out.println("B");
         if (grade >= 70 && grade< 80)
             System.out.println("C");
         if (grade >= 60 && grade< 70)
             System.out.println("D");
         if  (grade <= 59)
             System.out.println("F");

 getScores.close();

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first....

1. `Scanner getName = new Scanner(System.` is not right as a code...
2. No need of so many scanners... You can do all that with only one scanner.
3. Always close your resources after use... Its a good practice...
4. Also having too many `if`'s takes time in execution... It won't matter in this type of code but instead of using too many `if()` use an `if-else` ladder.

**Complete code....**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         String Name = new String();
         int quiz1;
         int quiz2;
         int quiz3;
         int quiz4;
         int mid1;
         int mid2;
         int Final;
         double grade;

         Scanner getScores = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter name with test scores with a space in between each, in the order of "
                 + "Quiz 1 Quiz 2 Quiz 3 Quiz 4\n Midterm 1 Midterm 2 and Final\n");//Shows the format needed
        Name = getScores.next();
        quiz1 = getScores.nextInt();
        quiz2 = getScores.nextInt();
        quiz3 = getScores.nextInt();
        quiz4 = getScores.nextInt();
        mid1 = getScores.nextInt();
        mid2 = getScores.nextInt();
        Final = getScores.nextInt();

         grade =( quiz1  *   .10 +   quiz2   *   .10 +   quiz3   *   .10 +   quiz4   *   .10 
                +    mid1    *   .20 +   mid2    *   .15 +   Final * .25);
         System.out.print(Name);
         if  (grade >= 90)
             System.out.println("A");
       else  if (grade >= 80 && grade< 90)
             System.out.println("B");
        else if (grade >= 70 && grade< 80)
             System.out.println("C");
        else if (grade >= 60 && grade< 70)
             System.out.println("D");
        else  (grade <= 59)
             System.out.println("F");

 getScores.close();

     }
```

Comment: Also try to give him some explanation about what he missed?

Comment: No, the OP doesn't want the user to write the name on a separate line. He/she wants all the inputs be on the same line with spaces in between. The call to `nextLine` in your code causes the name to be on a separate line.

Comment: Yes checked with input